# XLSX to CSV file convert for API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, xlsx

Im trying to convert .xlsx file to .csv file before i send it to the API (because it accepts only .csv files) ;

I am using package xlsx and i got this function that converts it for me but problem is that this function will make the user download the file, and i don't want that i just want that it saves it kinda in like a object so i can use it only for the api (and don't let know the user that its converted ).

Here is code:

```
    file.arrayBuffer().then(res => {
            let data = new Uint8Array(res)
            let workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: "array"})
            let first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0]
            let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name]
            let jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw: false, defval: null})
            let fileName;
            if (file) {
                fileName = file?.name.substring(0, file?.name?.indexOf("."))
            }
            let new_worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);
            let new_workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(new_workbook, new_worksheet, "csv_sheet")

            getRandomRows(jsonData)
            XLSX.writeFile(new_workbook, fileName + ".csv")
            
        })
```

Was wondering if there are other options too.

Comment: "Was wondering if there are other options too." What does your research into the problem tell you? You read the documentation of the library, right? Searched for other questions?

Comment: I read already the documentation and tried all of the options that the package gives me  . Also looked other sources but yet i couldnt solve my issue . Been stuck with this one long time thats why asked for help.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You'll note that one of the things asked for is evidence of research. One of those pieces of evidence would be the attempt you made to use a different method and the error you received, as mentioned in your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it this way :

```
        let dataToSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data)
        const dataFileCSV = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(dataToSheet, {raw: false, defval: null});
        let blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", dataFileCSV]);
        let fileBlob = new File([blob], "name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Readme from xlsx try to use `writeFileAsync` or just `write` instead of `writeFile` as it force browser to start download

Comment: These method didn't work . Console sends error:
```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unrecognized type undefined
    at write_zip_type (xlsx.js:21462)
    at Object.writeSync [as write] (xlsx.js:21556)
    at App.js:160 ```